# Run delete query until zero rows affected in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, duplicates, postgis

I'm using PostGIS to process some complex land use data. I have several cases were there were exact duplicate polygons created. I'd like to delete these duplicates, and I am currently using the following self-join SQL to remove the duplicates:

```
delete from landusetable where objectid in 
(select max(x.objectid) from landusetable x JOIN landusetable y ON 
ST_Equals(x.shape, y.shape) WHERE x.objectid <> y.objectid group by x.shape);
```

This works fine to remove the duplicate with the higher objectid value, however it only removes the highest objectid. If there are 3 or more duplicate polygons, I need to run this statement multiple times until the delete statement affects 0 rows, then I know I've removed all of the duplicates.

So, using a PL/pgSQL function or other control structure, how can I run the statement above multiple times until I receive "DELETE 0", then quit? I looked through the documentation, but I couldn't find how to receive the number of affected rows from the previous query using PL/pgSQL.

Any assistance you could provide would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The technique I use for deleting duplicate rows in SQL Server is by using a CTE combined with the ROW_NUMBER() function.  A little googling would suggest that technique should work in postgresql too, but I'm not certain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can incorporate `row_number()` into your query by using a subquery:

```
delete from landusetable
    where objectid in (select x.objectid
                       from (select x.objectid,
                                    ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by x.shape order by objectId) as seqnum
                             from landusetable x JOIN
                                  landusetable y
                                  ON ST_Equals(x.shape, y.shape)
                             WHERE x.objectid <> y.objectid
                            ) xy
                       where seqnum > 1
                      )
```

Of course, you could also put the subquery into a CTE, if you like.

In this case, using "standard" SQL results in a simpler query.  This version uses `where exists` rather than `in`:

```
delete from landusetable
    where exists (select 1
                  from landusetable lut2
                  where ST_Equals(lut2.shape, landusetable.shape) and
                        lut2.objectid > landusetable.objectid
                 )
```